# Pivot Table by Category

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

I have struggle in trying to have one specific id for multiple category.

For example, currently I have in Excel

```
**ID | category**
apple a/b/c
banana c
orange a/c/d
```

how do I show in pivot table that will show the following

```
**category | id (by count)**
a  2
b  1
c  3
d  1
```

currently when i have my pivot table it shows this instead

```
**category | id (by count)**
a/b/c  1
a/c/d  1
c      1
```

I have attached my Excel file for reviewing purposes. Please assist if possible with macros or vba code or formula would be really helpful!

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Maybe that's the wrong way to arrange your source data?  If you put multiple pieces of data into a single field then it will always be difficult to summarize and/or re-arrange.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you should have one column per category, instead of one column merging all data.
Then in your pivot you will have your option :
[image: Sample pivot table]

Answer (score 0):

You have to organize your data source like this to have the good pivot table :

[image]